# My stackoverflow careers page is not available

Tags: support, jobs, 404-not-found

I just filled my Careers profile from the invitation I received.

I've set up a Custom Profile URL but when I try to access it, I get a *Page Not Found* error.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your profile is currently private.

You can make it public from the Privacy Settings on the right-hand side of the profile editor. Then your CV will be accessible via the URL you selected.

Comment: Ah. silly me. Thanks!